# How can I use desktop app to get contents of resouce.pri file in metro app package

Tags: c#

How can I use desktop app to get contents of resource.pri file in metro app package?

I want to get the localizable displayName in manifest like ms:resource, Any direction?
Or could anybody here explain the structure about the resource.pri file? Many Thanks.